# How can I implement windows authentication in azure without approval?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

I've built a .net core 7 web application.

It implements windows authentication, and works nicely on premise.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(NegotiateDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddNegotiate();
```

I've deployed to an azure app service, and I get got this error when I browse to the application:

> InvalidOperationException: The Negotiate Authentication handler cannot
> be used on a server that directly supports Windows Authentication.
> Enable Windows Authentication for the server and the Negotiate
> Authentication handler will defer to it.

So I added a Microsoft Azure AD identity provider, which created for me a new app registration.   Now I can browse to the application, enter my credentials, but it once I do,  I get another dialog saying "Approval required, enter justification".  After I submit my request approval, I get an email saying my request was received.  I don't know who gets the approval request, or why a request is being generated.  We could have hundreds of employees using the application, and will eventually have dozens of applications, so an approval request might not be manageable.  Can it be turned off, or am I implementing the authentication wrong in the first place?

Approval Request:
[image]

Email:
[image]

Comment: You need to ask your Azure AD administrator to do admin consent for your app.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the right premissions, you might be able to grant consent on behalf of all users yourself. This ensures that end users will not be required to consent when using the application. To do this, navigate to your App Registration Overview and click on 'Go to Enterprise applications'. From there, click on the Permissions in the left menu. At this page you can grant admin consent to all users.

These global settings can be changed, but only by an administrator. How you can do that is described in this article: https://intercom.help/eventtemple/en/articles/5152672-need-admin-approval-approval-required-when-connecting-outlook-office365